# debugging javascript error in ie7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

All I get is this:

```
An error has occurred in the script on this page
line: 31
char: 5
error: expected identifier, string or number
code: 0
url: http://example.com
```

It's difficult to find that line since I have several external and internal scripts.

How can I debug this? (By the way, the scripts have no errors in chrome or firefox or ie8+)

Comment: Probably a dangling comma.  It's always a dangling comma.

Comment: Add line 31 into your answer from the page itself. Doesn't sound as though its coming from an external file as IE normally tells you it's a problem with an external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try debugging it with IE8's Developer Tools (press F12). You should be able to step through the JS code (from all your scripts) to find out what is wrong with line 31 / char 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can download IETester which lets you use various versions of IE (6-8) and has built-in developer tools.  They're not spectacular, but they're better than the nothing that old versions of IE provide.

Comment: His question is "How do I debug this?"  My answer is a suggestion for a tool to use to debug it.  I think it should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If it says it's on the page, then it means the page itself. If it was in an external file, it would indicate that the error occured in `something.js`.

Open up your webpage, right click on the page and select "View Source". Go to line 31 and try and see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also enable debugging for IE at

```
(Tools -> Options -> (uncheck) Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer).
```

After you disable it, IE will prompt you to debug when error occurs. Then you can debug with VS or MS script Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox with Firebug. Look at every external script around the line number mentioned in the error dialog. Trailing commas every time!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when try to to figure out what 's wrong with the code on IE7, after spending hours research and trying many different solutions, finally, the following two bars are great tools for me:

1) http://www.debugbar.com/

provide a convenience UI to with feature like source, style, DOM, Script, HTML check.

2) http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/Installing

The main advantage of this is providing a console for IE6 or IE7, so you can see what are the error (in the console log)

- Note:
- they are both free
- screen shot of both two toolbars

[image]